# How can I fill out and flatten pdfs, using php, on a shared hosting account?

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, shared-hosting

I would like to programmatically fill out and flatten pdf's (and then serve to the user). I am coding in php. I wanted to use PDFtk, but after contacting my hosting provider (godaddy), I was told it's not possible to install it on my shared hosting account.

I found [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/), which looks great for filling out the forms, but then how can I flatten them? I didn't see that FPDF can do that, is there a different php library that can? Or a tool that does not need sudo privilege to install? Something either free or with a small price tag. Thanks.

Comment: What is a "small price tag"? You may check out our [SetaPDF-FormFiller Lite](https://www.setasign.com/products/setapdf-formfiller/details/) component which does exactly what you are searching for and pricing starts at 180 EUR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using MPDF, which I think is based on FPDF, and I had to use PDFTK, a command-line tool.
https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/

Works great, really fast and you have a lot a useful functions (merge PDFs, remove password protection, add a watermak stamp...)

Comment: as i said in the question, i can't use pdftk

Comment: My bad, sorry. Do you have access to ghostscript ? There is often an old version of it even on shared hosting. I think it can work

Comment: i doubt i can install it. how would i know if there is an old version already there?

Comment: "which gs" or "gs --version" in shell_exec for example. If it's not there you'll  probably not be able to install it. In that case, just change your hosting. The best solution is still pdftk.

Comment: it's not so simple to just go and change my hosting! thanks anyway

Comment: You can also make your script a websevice and make it run on a cheap vps or a local computer that is always turned on (not as stupid as it sounds)

Comment: that crazy idea might work... the client has a vps for something else anyway. i also saw this, dont know if it will work. http://stackoverflow.com/a/36121174/354030

Comment: Yeah why not, if godaddy alows you to run functions like shell_exec or another variant it might work, but on most shared hostings you can't do that